# What is the best way to build a multi-language and multi-directions website with angular?

Tags: angular, multilingual

So I am going to build a fresh new website which has to be accessible to English, French, and Hebrew, note that Hebrew is RTL language.

I decided to build the website with Angular 6.
I was thinking about building two templates, one for each direction (LTR and RTL), and fill this templates with content respectively to the language that has been selected.

I was wondering if there is any other sufficient way to build an Angular 6 website which supports multi-directions?
I have read about i18n but I don't think it is the right solution as it doesn't provide solutions for directions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have made this example using service and pipe, it works perfectly.
You need to remove the folowing on your app : I have commented it.

```
import * as en from './i18n/en.json';
import * as de from './i18n/de.json';
import * as ar from './i18n/ar.json';

const langs = { ar: ar, en: en, de: de };
```

and active this line to import json files dynamically:

```
this.languagesObject = require(`./i18n/${value}.json`);
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-translator-using-service-and-pipe

Comment: not worked with plurarism... stop conting in 2.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-translator-using-service-and-pipe-jerkxq

Comment: @Willian What are you trying to do?

Comment: I trying make pluralism

Comment: Negative, 0, 1, 2 “more items... infinity”

Comment: is prossible help?

Comment: @Willian Please make an example and explain what you need to do, I can not understand in one word "pluralism" what you need.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-translator-using-service-and-pipe-4mid9o i need translate with replace number "tag" "no item." "1 item" "2 items." etc..

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't really understand what are trying to do, but this may help you `{{('compL' | tr)[more]}}` or explain it more

Comment: humm not undestand [more] i need replace compL#0#3 for condition...

Comment: "compL": [{"chave": [{"0": "@total", "legenda": "for total"}, {"1": "@rest", "legenda": "for restant"}], "negativo": "", "0":"Need item.", "1":"@rest item." ,"2":"@rest items."}]

Comment: `[more]` is the index of your object `{{('compL' | tr)[0]}}`

Comment: `('compL' | tr)` returns your object

Comment: try `{{('compL' | tr)[0][1]}}`

Comment: need replace @number dynamic

Comment: Ok, make an example including the expected result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65174993/multi-language-angular-condition-and-plural

Comment: Is This example helpful? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-translator-using-service-and-pipe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: there exemple no work 100% correct, i change the exemple https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-translator-using-service-and-pipe-3stzkg

Comment: i resolve the problem, more have code more clean?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is looking for a library to manage multilanguage in Angular2+.
You can use this library that rocks: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core.

Add it to your project with:

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core --save
```

Then import it in your AppModule:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot()
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then, a good practice would be to export it in a SharedModule so you don't have to import it in every module in your app (you would only need to import the SharedModule):

```
@NgModule({
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Reference: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Hope it helps!